# How to make slide show of video links?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-plugins, youtube

I have list of youtube video url's only, and no way to add images for each video as thumbnail image.

Now I want to make this list of youtube videos as a Slide show of jcarousel or any other jquery slide show.

This means I want to display youtube videos as slide show.

How can I achieve without uploading thumbnail image of each video?

Answer (score 0):

1. Set up your HTML/JS as the jcarousel need it with dummy data
2. Make an array or object with your youtube IDs
3. Loop your array or object to create multiple items in your jcarousel
4. Receive Video thumbnails inside your loop with this method: `http://img.youtube.com/vi/[YOUTUBE-VIDEO-ID]/0.jpg`
5. There are multiple thumbnails in different dimensions. Try yourself
   by using `1.jpg`, `2.jpg`,...
6. Use the embed version of the youtube player to display the video. Example Code: `<iframe width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube-nocookie.com/embed/[YOUTUBE-VIDEO-ID]" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>`